# Silverlight XAML - UserControl vs Page

Tags: silverlight, xaml

When creating Silverlight pages, when should one use "UserControl" as the base class, and when should you use "Page" as the base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Page if you want to use the navigation features

Comment: +1: Specifically though, use page if you want to use the *built-in* navigation features. You can code up replacement navigation systems in Silverlight that just use normal UserControls. Page just provides a common base class to hang functionality & state.